# How do I create a Map using Java stream API when the key is a different class attribute?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
 class Manager {
    public int id,  // primary key 
    private String name,
    public Department department,
 }

  class Department {
     public int deptId, //primary key 
    public String name,
  }
```

I need to create a Map in which

- key -> Department Id
- value -> Manager Name

Given that I have array of Managers which contains list of ManagerEntity

```
ex. [new Manager(1,"John Doe", 'ObjectOfTypeDepartemnt' ]
```

I need to create Map using Java stream

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: *I have array of Managers which contains list of ManagerEntity* clear this part. What you want list or array ?

Comment: I Need in Value List of Manager.
I ensured that the Departement is not null.
I tried :

`managerList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(groupingBy(Manager::getDepartment::getDeptId, Manager::getName)`


but this syntax is not working 
I know this is where I am wrong `Manager::getDepartment::getDeptId`but dont know what syntax to follow

Comment: Does a department have multiple managers? Relation between manager and department is not specified. Add these details in your question so that it will help others also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Stream API solution. Remember, you have to filter out first these managers, which departments are `null` to prevent fail on NPE while getting the department ID.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = list.stream()           // Stream<Manager>
    .filter(m-> m.getDepartment() != null)         // Stream<Manager> with departments
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(                     // collected as Map<Integer, String>
        m-> manager.getDepartment().getDeptId(),   // ... key is the department ID
        Manager::getName));                        // ... value is the manager's name
```

In case the origin is not `List<Manager> list` but `Manager[] array`, then use a slighty different approach to create a `Stream<Manager>`:

```
Arrays.stream(array)...
```